# Opening application from notification

Tags: android, android-activity, android-pendingintent

Let's say that we have Activity which displays funny picture and name it FunnyActivity. This Activity can be launched from MainActivity, which is base Activity in out application, after clicking button. We want also to push some notifications sometimes and when user clicks on notification this FunnyActivity should be launched. So we add this part of code:

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, FunnyActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notificationIntent, 0);
```

and this PendingIntent is using in notification builder

```
setContentIntent(intent)
```

Of course FunnyActivity is beautifully launching, but we want to open MainActivity when user clicks back button on FunnyActivity.

How can we achieve that? Please remember that when user came back to MainActivity he can open FunnyActivity again from button.

Comment: I don't know the standard solution and this might sound like a hack but, one of the things you can do is override `onBackPressed()` in FunnyActivity and start MainActivity with proper flags there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Intent for the activity to open when user selects the notification
Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);

// Use TaskStackBuilder to build the back stack and get the PendingIntent
PendingIntent pendingIntent =
        TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                        // add all of DetailsActivity's parents to the stack,
                        // followed by DetailsActivity itself
                        .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
                        .addNextIntent(detailsIntent);
                        .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Source: [Create back stack when starting the activity](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#CreateBackStack)

Comment: Seems right anwser! But where is use of detailsIntent?

Comment: @ThirdMartian after .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)

Comment: @ThirdMartian I updated the answer, also 'upIntent' is the intent for the MainActivity you want to open on back pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, FunnyActivity.class);

                    // Adds the back stack
                    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
                    // Adds the Intent to the top of the stack
                    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

Intent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)/*.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))*/
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentTitle(title)
                            .setContentText(msg)
                            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                            .setAutoCancel(true);
```

This is how you can achieve solution to your problem. Hope this helps you